# Rails and Postgres: ActiveRecord::LockWaitTimeout: PG::LockNotAvailable when using Sidekiq and advisory locks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We recently had a complete outage in our Rails application caused by Sidekiq jobs that raised thousands of `ActiveRecord::LockWaitTimeout: PG::LockNotAvailable` exceptions.

As far as our understanding goes, these exceptions in Sidekiq should never be able to take down the app like it did, because Sidekiq runs on it's own connection pool to the database, with sufficiente connections.

This is our database.yml:

```yaml
pool: <%= Sidekiq.server? ? (Sidekiq.options[:concurrency].to_i + 5) : (ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS").to_i + 2) %>
connect_timeout: 5
variables:
  statement_timeout: 15s
  lock_timeout: 10s
```

- We run 4 puma workers, each with 5 threads (ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") == 5). So puma.rb.j2 contains:

```rb
workers 4
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS")
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count
```

If you do the math `(12 sidekiq concurrency + 5 for safety) + (4 puma workers * (5 for each puma worker + 2 for safety))`, you'll get 45 `(12 + 5) + (4 * (5 + 2))`.

Our `postgresql.conf` `max_connections` is the default `100`, which seems to be the double of what we need.

How the meltdown happened:

In our application we have a simple `LockManager::with_transaction_lock` method, that acquires an advisory lock and executes a block of code.

We use it to rate-limit calls to one external API.

```rb
class LockManager
  def self.with_transaction_lock(lock_name)
    lock_id = self.generate_lock_id(lock_name)

    # per documentation, pg_advisory_xact_lock  works the same as pg_advisory_lock, except the lock is automatically released at the end of the current transaction and cannot be released explicitly.
    lock_and_execute = lambda do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(#{lock_id})")
      yield
    end

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction_open? ?
      lock_and_execute.call : ActiveRecord::Base.transaction { lock_and_execute.call }

    private_class_method def self.generate_lock_id(lock_name)
      Zlib.crc32(lock_name.to_s)
    end

  end
end
```

We queued ~ 1000 jobs that had this code:

```rb
tax_receipt.with_lock do

  # return early if already transfered

  LockManager.with_transaction_lock("foo_external_api") do

    # post to the external API to transfer the tax_receipt and update tax_receipt with the status.

  end

end
```

The rationale being: we first grab a row lock in the tax_receipt instance (so we never transfer a tax_receipt twice) and then we grab the advisory lock to the `foo_external_api` and do the transfer, finishing with the update.

It seemed like a reasonable approach and it served well for over one year.

However, yesterday this took down our entire app; our error tracking had thousands of `ActiveRecord::LockWaitTimeout: PG::LockNotAvailable` exceptions, which is expected due to the `lock_timeout: 10s` that is set, but it should raise the exception and go to the Sidekiq retry queue.

As soon as we stopped Sidekiq's queue, we were back online immediately.

Questions:

1. How did this manage to bring the entire application down if Sidekiq has it's own pool of connections to the database, and we are under half of postgres max_connections?
2. What's wrong with the `with_lock` + `with_transaction_lock` we took?